# The expression "Comment se fait-il que"

Tags: expressions, questions

Is this phrase used to express criticism or surprise rather than to ask a reason? How is it different from using "pourquoi"?

> Et **comment se fait-il qu**'elle ne m'ait pas amnistiée sitôt couronnée ?

Incidentally, is the word "sitôt" used in a more formal register than "dès"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, "Comment se fait-il" does not mean the same as "pourquoi", as both of them require an explanation.

On one hand, use "Comment se fait-il" when you require an explanation about something that happened, when you expected the opposite. This idiom precise some kind of surprise, disappointment or anger.

On the other hand, "pourquoi" is more general and does not carry those undertones.

Finally, "sitôt" is not much more formal, but this word makes the sentence shorter. Indeed, if you want to use "dès" conjunction, it requires a subordinate clause :

> Et comment se fait-il qu'elle ne m'ait pas amnistiée dès qu'elle fut couronnée?

Comment: Regarding the part "dès qu'elle **fut** couronnée", is it wrong in casual speech to say "dès qu'elle **avait été** couronnée" or "dès qu'elle **a été** couronnée" or  "dès qu'elle **était** couronnée"? Merci.

Comment: "dès qu'elle a été couronnée" sounds correct, but "dès qu'elle avait été couronnée" or "dès qu'elle était couronnée" are not : "était" describes a state, while "a été" describes an event.